# Python - Get list of every permutation of a list of a set number of characters

Tags: python

I have a list of 7 characters. How would I programmatically create every permutation of the the letters shuffled (I know that the number of lists would be 7 factorial).

I know how to shuffle a list, but I assume that wouldn't be efficient to just keep shuffling the list, and then checking if i've already created that permutation and keep going til I hit the number of possibilities.

Comment: 7 letters, huh? Do you also want to check to see whether these letter permutations form a word in a dictionary? :)

Comment: yeah, playing my sister in w.w.f.  She's good with english, I'm good with math.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations("abc"))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the [permutations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module?